# How to calculate Joint Probability of more than two random variable in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have written the following code which read the data(which has four parameter) from a file and calculate the mean and co-variance matrix of Multivariate distribution. Parameter mu and sigma is calculated using MLE(Maximum Likelihood Method).

```
library(mvtnorm)
df <- read.csv("../data/dataset.train", header=FALSE)
mu = colMeans(df)
sigma <- matrix(0, nrow = ncol(df), ncol = ncol(df))
for(row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  temp = df[row,]-mu
   sigma = sigma + as.matrix(t(temp)) %*% as.matrix(temp)
}
sigma = sigma / nrow(df)
```

Now I want to find the following probability $P(a1 < X1 < a2,X2 = b1,X3 = c1,d1 < X4 < d2)$, How can I compute the this probability.

My Effort:
I have tried using

```
pmvnorm(lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, mean=rep(0, length(lower)),corr=NULL, sigma=NULL, algorithm = GenzBretz(), ...) method
```

by putting lower and upper limit following

```
lower = [a1,b1,c1,d1] and upper = [a2,b1,c1,d2]
```

but it gives the error "lower==upper". I think this is because my second and third value in lower and upper is same.
But I don't know how to compute this in R.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A note on your syntax: you switch between `<-` and `=` as the assignment operator. This does not affect your results, but is not ideal.

Comment: Are x2 and x3 continuous? then the probability of x2=b1 is zero

Comment: yes.... x2 and x3 are continuous. but then how dmvnorm() method compute the probability at a particular point even if random variable is continuous....

Comment: Its calculating the density not the probability (more a relative probability compared to the other values of the variable). An example, `dnorm(0, mean=0, sd=0.01)` is greater than one so therefore not a probability - depends on the units of the x-axis. The area under the curve gives the probability, for a particular region.

Comment: @tourism: A hyper box with any single pair of the upper and lower dimensions being the same will have volume zero. This doesn't appear to be coding problem at the moment, but rather a conceptual problem. If you don't delete it, then it should be moved to CrossValidated.com. If you want this to stay on SO then put in (distinct) numerical upper and lower values for each of a,b,c,d.